# Self-joins, subqueries, or something else?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, query-optimization

Ok so I need to work out the best way to perform some dynamically built queries in my database.

I have two tables `MA_Objects` and `MA_Attributes`. `MA_Objects` contains a list of users and has columns representing single-valued attributes related to that user. (For example, first name, surname). `MA_Attributes` contains multi-valued attributes for that user, (eg email addresses).

MA_Attributes stores value pairs consisting of a mandatory attribute name, and an attribute value columns, that depends on its data type. So every column will have an attributeName, and if that attribute is a string, then its value will be in attributeValueString. The other attributeValue* columns must be null.

The table structure is below

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MA_Objects](
    [id] [uniqueidentifier] ROWGUIDCOL  NOT NULL,
    [firstName] [nvarchar](400) NULL,
    [givenNames] [nvarchar](400) NULL,
    [middleName] [nvarchar](400) NULL,
    [surname] [nvarchar](400) NULL,
    [objectclass] [nvarchar](400) NULL,
    [supervisor] [uniqueidentifier] NULL

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MA_Attributes](
    [id] [uniqueidentifier] ROWGUIDCOL  NOT NULL,
    [objectId] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [attributeName] [nvarchar](30) NOT NULL,
    [attributeValueString] [nvarchar](400) NULL,
    [attributeValueInt] [bigint] NULL,
    [attributeValueBinary] [varbinary](800) NULL,
    [attributeValueReference] [uniqueidentifier] NULL
```

`[MA_Attributes].[objectId]` is a FK to `[MA_Objects].[id]`

So, this application needs to be able to find an object ID from the MA_Objects table, by querying those attribute values. The search might be as simple as finding the user with the mail address "test@test.com" or it might be a complex mix of attributes stored in both tables (with a mix of AND and OR criteria).

The MA_Objects table will have about 500k records in it. The MA_Attributes table will have tens of millions of records in it. Performance is important.

My question is, am I best to used nested SELECT subqueries, or a series of self-joins to achieve this? Or something completely different? Both seem to work, and I'm having trouble making sense of the actual query plan to see what is going on under the hood.

Here is the same query in both formats

SubQuery Model

```
select distinct 
    [o].[id] 
from [dbo].[MA_Objects] [o] 
left join [dbo].[MA_Attributes] [a] 
on ([o].[id] = [a].[objectId]) 
where 
(
    [o].[objectClass] = N'user' 
and
    (
        (
            [o].[supervisor] in ('6213F48A-A97F-48E2-AFD7-2EF830C4DAA8', '0917EC45-CA23-41F5-911C-B92A90140AFD', '69B1DA67-4E3C-406E-8B78-B4633800B491')
        ) 
    and 
        (   
        [o].[id] in 
            (
                select [a].[objectId] 
                from [dbo].[MA_Attributes] [a] 
                where
                (
                    (
                        [a].[attributeName] = N'mailAlternateAddresses' 
                    and 
                        [a].[attributeValueString] in (N'test.test@test.com', N'test3.test3@test.com')
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    and 
        (   
        [o].[id] in 
            (
                select [a].[objectId] 
                from [dbo].[MA_Attributes] [a] 
                where
                (
                    (
                        [a].[attributeName] = N'objectSids'
                    and 
                        [a].[attributeValueBinary] in (0x0001020304, 0x0007070707)
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    and 
        (   
        [o].[id] in 
            (
                select [a].[objectId] 
                from [dbo].[MA_Attributes] [a] 
                where
                (
                    (
                        [a].[attributeName] = N'expiryDates' 
                    and
                        [a].[attributeValueInt] in (44, 77, 99)
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    )
)
```

Self Join model

```
select distinct 
    [o].[id] 
from [dbo].[MA_Objects] [o] 
left join [dbo].[MA_Attributes] [a] 
on ([o].[id] = [a].[objectId]) 
where 
(
    [o].[objectClass] = N'user' 
and
    (
        (
            [o].[supervisor] in ('6213F48A-A97F-48E2-AFD7-2EF830C4DAA8', '0917EC45-CA23-41F5-911C-B92A90140AFD', '69B1DA67-4E3C-406E-8B78-B4633800B491')
        ) 
        and 
        (   
            [o].[id] in 
            (
                select [a].[objectId] 
                from [dbo].[MA_Attributes] [a] 
                left join [dbo].[MA_Attributes] [a0] on ([a].[objectId] = [a0].[objectId]) 
                left join [dbo].[MA_Attributes] [a1] on ([a].[objectId] = [a1].[objectId]) 
                left join [dbo].[MA_Attributes] [a2] on ([a].[objectId] = [a2].[objectId]) 
                where 
                (
                    [a].[objectId] = [a0].[objectId]
                and 
                    [a].[id] <> [a0].[id] 
                and 
                    [a].[objectId] = [a1].[objectId] 
                and 
                    [a].[id] <> [a1].[id] 
                and 
                    [a].[objectId] = [a2].[objectId] 
                and 
                    [a].[id] <> [a2].[id] 
                and 
                    (
                        (
                            [a0].[attributeName] = N'mailAlternateAddresses' 
                        and 
                            [a0].[attributeValueString] in (N'test.test@test.com', N'test3.test3@test.com')
                        )
                    and 
                        (
                            [a1].[attributeName] = N'objectSids'
                        and 
                            [a1].[attributeValueBinary] in (0x0001020304, 0x0007070707)
                        )
                    and 
                        (
                            [a2].[attributeName] = N'expiryDates' 
                        and
                            [a2].[attributeValueInt] in (44, 77, 99)
                        )
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    )
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nested select statements almost guarantee to have worst performance, SQL Server is required to go after table each time.

Your self join statement is still sub-select which you should rewrite as follows.

```
SELECT o.*
    FROM @MA_Objects AS o
    LEFT OUTER JOIN @MA_Attributes AS at1
        ON o.id = at1.objectId
    LEFT OUTER JOIN @MA_Attributes AS at2
        ON o.id = at2.objectId
    LEFT OUTER JOIN @MA_Attributes AS at3
        ON o.id = at3.objectId
    WHERE o.objectclass = N'user'
        AND o.supervisor IN ( '6213F48A-A97F-48E2-AFD7-2EF830C4DAA8', '0917EC45-CA23-41F5-911C-B92A90140AFD',
                              '69B1DA67-4E3C-406E-8B78-B4633800B491' )
        AND (
              at1.attributeName = N'mailAlternateAddresses'
              AND at1.attributeValueString IN ( N'test.test@test.com', N'test3.test3@test.com' ) )
        AND (
              at2.attributeName = N'objectSids'
              AND at2.attributeValueBinary IN ( 0x0001020304, 0x0007070707 ) )
        AND (
              at3.attributeName = N'expiryDates'
              AND at3.attributeValueInt IN ( 44, 77, 99 ) )
```

`Join` operation will be faster than `IN` operation. This way you will only go after limitted number of rows in each `JOIN` only rows that match your `o.id` will be returned and evaluated.

When you want to write great performance query you should try to reduce number of rows as soon as possible and only work with a subset that you need.

Therefore depending on the information that you need to search for you will need to rewrite query accordingly to reduce number of records as soon as possible to maintain high performance.

Note: Forgot to mention that I changed your tables into Table variables to use intellisense

Comment: Ok, that looks and feels a lot better. Interestingly, the query resulted in the same execution plan as some of the other experimental queries I was running, but this is *much* more readable and easier to construct as well.